# Can the browser access to camera (independent of OS) and other applications on the laptop?

Tags: operating-system, camera

we want to create an internet platform, where for registered users the following is done:

1) Tracking of the applications they open during they are "checked in" on the page

2) Tracking of their web surfing

3) In regular periods a picture is automatically taken by the built-in camera of the laptop (not Smartphone) and uploaded to the platform.

I know, sounds like brave new world;)

Is a server-sided framework like `Rails` with client code in `JQuery` sufficient for it?
Or is an own client application in e.g. `objective-C` for `MacOS` necessary?
Thanks,
R

Answer (score 0):

You can do **2** using almost any of the web application frameworks + javascript.

**1** is impossible unless the there is an application running in the desktop or a browser extension that is communicating with your website.

However the **3** sounds very alarming from a privacy standpoint. But if the users are willing and is aware of it then it's not an issue.

As far as I know, JavaScript does not natively support accessing the web camera. But Flash does!

Fortunately for you there is a library which combines both Flash and JavaScript that can take a web cam snapshot. It's called [jpegcam](http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/). There seems to be another one called [jquery web cam plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/). Also read this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922723/using-a-webcam-with-javascript

Comment: Wait hold on, does tracking of the application they open means what they open on their desktop? If yes, I've updated the answer.